# Is it possible to stop a JNI call

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I developed a `c` library. I call The `c` functions of the library from my `JAVA` code with `JNI`:

```
jstring Java_com_example_openafreerdp_UnboundedService_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    ...
}
```

The `JNI` function is called from java in this way:

```
public class UnboundedService extends Service {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hellondk");
    }
    private native String invokeNativeFunction();

    private class JniBackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... ss) {
            final String str = invokeNativeFunction();          
            return str;
        }
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        JniBackGround task = new JniBackGround();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.any.com" });
    }
}
```

Now my C function take long time to fulfill execution. And I want to Add a button to stop this execution. How I can stop it with JAVA?

Comment: you need to call `invokeNativeStopFunction` from button on click listener ... which will have similar body to your native: `{
    ...
}` or just call `AsyncTask.cancel`

Comment: @Selvin smells like an answer...

Comment: @Selvin I tried `task.cancel(true)` but it does not stop the C function execution neither the task

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead it was a little bit ironical comment, he did not show us what is going on inside invokeNativeFunction in native code ... but ... if fx there is some kind of inf loop it `while(true)` he can always use `while(someFlag)` and set `someFlag` to false inside this new `invokeNativeStopFunction` ... if he is using some curl library call(which i doubt, because url is not passed to native) he can cancel curl request there ... and so on and so forth ...

Comment: @Selvin your last comment is good and helped me to find a solution. Thank you. Could you please make it as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

if fx there is some kind of inf loop it `while(true)` he can always use `while(someFlag)` and set `someFlag` to false inside this new `invokeNativeStopFunction` ... if he is using some curl library call(which i doubt, because url is not passed to native) he can cancel curl request there ... and so on and so forth ...
                    – Selvin